# Google Sheet Parse Error when using importjson API

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I'm using custom json function in google sheets but it shows parse error

```js
/**
* Imports JSON data to your spreadsheet Ex: IMPORTJSON("http://myapisite.com","city/population")
* @param url URL of your JSON data as string
* @param xpath simplified xpath as string
* @customfunction
*/
function IMPORTJSON(url,xpath){
  
  try{
    // /rates/EUR
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var content = res.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);
    
    var patharray = xpath.split("/");
    //Logger.log(patharray);
    
    for(var i=0;i<patharray.length;i++){
      json = json[patharray[i]];
    }
    
    //Logger.log(typeof(json));
    
    if(typeof(json) === "undefined"){
      return "Node Not Available";
    } else if(typeof(json) === "object"){
      var tempArr = [];
      
      for(var obj in json){
        tempArr.push([obj,json[obj]]);
      }
      return tempArr;
    } else if(typeof(json) !== "object") {
      return json;
    }
  }
  catch(err){
      return "Error getting data";  
  }
  
}
```

I don't know what is happening here since my friend next to me used the exact same json and it works for them

here is the function I am using in my cell : `=IMPORTJSON(JOIN("","http://shipit-api.herokuapp.com/api/guess/",I3),"0")`

I know that Parse error means that google does not understand the function written, but how can google does not understand it in my googlesheet but my friend's googlesheet just understood it fine

Comment: Hello Riza, I assume that the JSON returned from calling the URL may be malformed. What is the contents in `I3`? Or, rather, if you manually visit the URL after joining it with the contents in `I3`, what is the result obtained? Cheers

Comment: the content is tracking number, and this is used to fetch "carrier" and status data, the code above is to fetch carrier data, which will return "usps". the problem here is google seems to not understand the formula even though it should understand the formula written. because I use this code on my friend's googlesheet and it works. just not with mine

Comment: to clarify, there is nothing wrong with the code. I have been experimenting with other Googlesheets, they works. it is only my own Googlesheet which failed to parse the function, this is what makes me confused.  I am using the same googlesheet like other but why is it my own sheet is the one that cannot parse the function

Comment: Could it perhaps be the value in `I3`? Please check what value do you have in there. Setting it to 6 for me results in "Node Not Available". Also, please make sure that the function you have in your Sheet is exactly the following: `=IMPORTJSON(JOIN("","http://shipit-api.herokuapp.com/api/guess/", I3),"0")`. Kindly let me know of your results. Cheers

Comment: "Node Not Available" would be the correct result since the content must a string of characters. how did you get that result? I copy pasted exactly the code you wrote in your comment and it is still parse error

Comment: I literally just copy-pasted your code into the script editor, saved it, and copy-pasted above formula. Could you try just doing this on a brand-new Sheets document? Cheers